Equivalent description of the existence of limits of multi-variable functions
I was recently studying the limit of a multivariable function at a certain point. My teacher and the various encyclopedias I consulted all mentioned that：
"The limit of a multi-variable function at a certain point exists if and only if the limit approaching the point from any path will exist and have the same value."
But multivariable function limits are strictly defined by the ϵ-δ language. So, are these two propositions really mathematically equivalent?
How to describe the so-called "arbitrary path"?
I myself tried to use a composite of an arbitrary vector function r(t) (with some restrictions)and a multi-variable function f to describe the "arbitrary path", and used ϵ-δ language to prove that the left side can be deduced to the right side. But I cannot prove the other way around.
Are both sides really equivalent?If they are equivalent, how can we provide a reasonable mathematical description of "arbitrary path" and give a formal proof of this Equivalence?

A more basic notion is that of an "arbitrary sequence" of points approaching the given point, which you may recall for single-variable limits as the sequential formulation of a limit (see also here). What you're looking for is an analogue of the one-variable limit result that the limit exists if and only if both one-sided limits exist and are equal, which is dealt with in the question cited for "This question already has answers here".
